# Mg2+ ion formation

Tags: energy, electrons, ions, atoms, ionization-energy

Why does Mg not form a Mg+1 ion, even though its second ionization energy is much higher than the first ionization energy?
(I know that an ion should resemble the noble gas closest to the element from which it was formed (at least in the p and s blocks), but the question is why).
I saw that there is a similar question on the site, but I want to understand it atomically and not by enthalpy.
(I mean I want to understand it according to considerations such as whether because there is a decrease in the energy level from Mg+1 to Mg+2 (from n=3 to n=2) energy is released and the energy it emits is more than the energy needed to go from n=3 to n=2 or based on similar considerations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about monatomic ions, then we have to consider the balance between ionization energy and electrostatic attraction. When we go to $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ instead of just $\ce{Mg^{1+}}$, the electrostatic attraction to anions such as chloride or hydroxide is stronger and the energy saved from that could be enough to allow the more costly additional ionization. Roughly speaking, at least under conditions we encounter everyday, an extra ion charge can balance out about $3000$ kJ/mol of ionization energy, and the second ionization energy of magnesium comes in well under that. However the third ionization energy, involving an electron from the neon core, is far too high.

Magnesium does form *diatomic* $\ce{Mg2^{2+}}$ ions in certain complexes; these are made more stable than a monatomic ion would be by a magnesium-magnesium bond (which may have some ion-electride character[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp109547w), i.e. a superposition of $\ce{Mg^+–Mg^+}$ with $\ce{Mg^{2+}[e_2^{2-}]Mg^{2+}}$). Such compounds are widespread enough to earn [an article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_valent_magnesium_compounds).

**Reference**

1. Platts, J. A.; Overgaard, J.; Jones, C.; Iversen, B. B.; Stasch, A., "First Experimental Characterization of a Non-nuclear Attractor in a Dimeric Magnesium(I) Compound," *J. Phys. Chem. A*, 2011, **115**, 194-200, DOI: 10.1021/jp109547w

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.
I just want to make it clear. If I understood you correctly, then it actually happens because the electrostatic attraction between a Mg2+ ion and a certain anion is stronger than the electrostatic attraction between Mg1+ and the same anion, and this additional energy is greater (usually) than the second ionization energy, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yup, that's it.